# Different kind of UTF8 decoding in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I have searched a lot about UTF8 decoding, but not found the answer yet.

I receive an UTF-8 decode NSString from my NSXMLParser:

```
NSString *tempString = @"Test message readability is Ã³kÃ©";
```

In someway I can't find the way to change this encoded text to:

```
Test message readability is óké
```

I could tell all the options I tried but I don't think that should be necessary. Could please some help?

Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NSXMLParser` will treat the text using the character encoding that the XML specifies. I believe in your case the XML do not specify UTF-8 explicitly.

The text seems to be ISO Latin 1. If you can not do anything about the server generating the XML then you can apply this hack:

```
char* tempString = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tempString];
```

I have verified that this works by testing this from the GDB prompt:

```
po [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)[@"Test message readability is Ã³kÃ©" cStringUsingEncoding:5]]
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Xcode gave me a warning to use 'const char*'instead of 'char'. I suppose this does not give me any memory leaks? I am not used to using char. But if I understand you well, you are saying the XML file is not saved the right way for UTF-8, right?

Comment: No leaks here, and adding the `const` is the right thing to do. And yes, I believe the server either do not specify what character encoding is used, or it is specifying the wrong encoding.

Comment: The weird part is, that when I create an own xml file echoing it by php, in my browser it shows the right character, in objective-c it does change to the wrong characters...

Comment: Do you use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` xml declaration at the head of the document?

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. What you want is:

```
char *s = "Test message readability is Ã³kÃ©";
//Note: this is a one-byte-character C string, not an NSString!
NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithCString:s encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also keep in mind that when you initialize string constants, what actually goes to program memory depends on the encoding of the current file. If it's already UTF-8, then the characters will be doubly-encoded - you'll get characters Ã,³, etc. encoded as UTF8 in the C string.

In other words, using a string constant is probably a wrong move to begin with. Please give more context to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I receive XML that states encoding="UTF-8". One of the elements contains a string with characters like é and à. But when I open the XML in my browser, I already found these Ã³kÃ© characters. The thing is: when I reopen the text in TextWrangler(textEditor app) as UTF-8, it shows the right characters, do I reopen it as Windows Latin 1, it gives me the  Ã³kÃ©. Oh and your example does not work, I already tried!

Comment: If the XML is in UTF8, then opening it as Windows Latin 1 would give you wrong characters, that's to be expected. The question is, what are you trying to accomplish *in code* in the first place? Initializing an NSString from a string literal (either directly or via a C-string) is NOT equivalent to what NSXMLParser is giving you - there's an extra encoding layer that is the source file encoding.

Comment: I get an XML file from someone else that shows the wrong characters: Ã³kÃ© in my xml when parsing it. I see the same 'wrong' characters when opening the XML url in my browser. Is there a way to convert the string or loaded XMLString to the right characters?

Comment: My first thoughts are that the xml-file is not saved as UTF-8 but does declare itself in the header as UTF8, causing the wrong characters

Answer (score 1):

Standart encoding and decoding like this:

For encoding:

```
NSString *content =  [bodyTextView.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

For decoding:

```
NSString *decodedString = [msg.content stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```