# Incorrect decoding of known UTF-8 string from server

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, utf8-decode

In my application, I am getting some string values from a server, but I'm not ending up with the right string.

`بسيط`  this is the string from server side, but what I am getting is   `Ø¨Ø³ÙØ·`

I tried to test the response string in an online decoder:

http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode

It is UTF-8 encoded, but I couldn't decode the string on the iPhone side.

I took a look at these Stack Overflow links as reference

[Converting escaped UTF8 characters back to their original form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860867/converting-escaped-utf8-characters-back-to-their-original-form-in-ios-objective/7861345#7861345)
[unicode escapes in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893879/unicode-escapes-in-objective-c)
[utf8_decode for objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896221/utf8-decode-for-objective-c)

but none of them helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** the issue  from this link

[Different kind of UTF8 decoding in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846490/different-kind-of-utf8-decoding-in-nsstring)

NSString *string = @"Ø¨Ø³ÙØ·";

I tried

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]]
```

this method

Thank You.

Comment: This doesn't sound like you've actually solved something. I hope you don't get paid for "solutions" like this.

Comment: @mvds See i can solve my problem by the above method, i posted this here for helping others finding same solutions , may be it will helpful for others

Comment: @mvds whats wrong with this , utf8 encoded string can be decoded by using the above method.And i clearly mentioned that the solution solved my issue , So you tell me what would be the right answer for this question?...i ddnt find any thing helpful in your answer !!!!!!!sorry

Comment: I've clearly stated what's wrong with it. The most obvious thing is the magic number **5**. Please explain to me what the number 5 is doing there. You have a bug somewhere in your code (reading in UTF8 as if it were ISO-8859-1) and you have not fixed it, but put in the "reverse" bug to work around it.

Comment: 5 means NSISOLatin1StringEncoding

Comment: Ok, lets start by putting `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` in there instead of the number 5. Not everyone in the world knows that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand from your question the following points:

1. Do you have access on the server side (I mean the programming of it)?
2. How do you send and receive data to the server?

For the first question I will assume that the server is programmed to send you text in UTF-8 encoding.

Now on the iPhone if you are sending to the server using sockets use the following:

```
NSString *messageToSend = @"The text in the language you like";
const uint8_t *str = (uint8_t *) [messageToSend cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self writeToServer:str];
```

Where the function `writeToServer` is your function that will send the data to the server.

If you are willing to put the data in a SQLite3 database use:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [@"The text in the language you like" UTF8String], -1, NULL);
```

If you are receiving the data from the server (again using sockets) do the following:

```
[rowData appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
NSString *strRowData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rowData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I hope this covers all the cases you need.

Answer (score 0):

Without any source it is hard to say anything conclusive, but at some point you are interpreting a `UTF-8` encoded string as `ISO-8859-1`, and (wrongfully) converting it to `UTF-8`:

## Analysis for string 'بسيط':

- raw length: 8
- logical length: 4
- raw bytes:  `0xD8 0xA8 0xD8 0xB3 0xD9 0x8A 0xD8 0xB7`
- interpreted as ISO-8859-1 (Ø¨Ø³ÙØ·):  `0xC3 0x98 0xC2 0xA8 0xC3 0x98 0xC2 0xB3 0xC3 0x99 0xC2 0x8A 0xC3 0x98 0xC2 0xB7`

So at some point you should probably find some reference to `ISO-8859-1` in your code. Find it and remove it.